# Curl Sending data to external website and redirect

Tags: php, curl

I am currently connecting to an external url and sending it an xml file which is url encoded. I am using CURL to send this across which is working fine.

**Problem**:
When you user goes on the index.html and enters in the amount, presses submit, they get taken to post.php (where the form is submitting to CURL).

So information gets submitted fine but the URL follow does not work. What i mean by that is, on post.php, it downloads all the response from that page and then after a while it just fails.

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'postdata=' . urlencode(xmlGrab()));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');

// Download the given URL, and return output
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$headers = substr($output, 0, $curl_info["header_size"]); //split out header
$redirect = curl_getinfo($ch)['redirect_url'];

header('HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect');
header("Location: $redirect");

// Close the cURL resource, and free system resources
curl_close($ch);
```

**I thought that if i disable CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION and manually found the redirect_url and then proceeded to go to that header, it would work. But the data is no longer found on that.**

**Scenario**:

- User Submits a post http://localhost:8888/post.php
- Post.php contains a connection to google.co.uk
- Post.php connects and makes a post to google.co.uk
- The request downloads google.co.uk?q=blahblah to post.php
- post.php looks exactly like google.co.uk?q=blahblah
- 3 seconds later, it redirects to http;//localhost:8888/?q=blahblah

**What i want to achieve?**:

- User Submits a post http://localhost:8888/post.php
- Post.php contains a connection to google.co.uk
- Post.php connects and makes a post to google.co.uk
- It redirects properly to google.co.uk?q=blahblah
- User is now on google.co.uk and not on dev environment

Comment: do you echo your response ?

Comment: @HassanAhmed, obvious, coz OP stated that *post.php looks exactly like google.co.uk?q=blahblah* :)

Comment: @Mubin i only wanted to make sure of that :)

Comment: it happened to me once, so I went up to that page, build its `DOM` again, and after that, it stopped redirecting.

Comment: @HassanAhmed Yes the google.co.uk?q=blahblah all the html contained within that is downloaded to post.php so it looks like what i want. But it after a few seconds, it redirects back to my local page (no idea why)

Comment: @Mubin Thanks for helping - may i ask how you resolved it?

Comment: when you get response printed on the screen, either call `exit()` or `die`(hit browser's stop button if it doesn't work), and `view source`, as it's clear that `JS` is disabled, so I'm thinking that there should be a statement some thing like this `header( "refresh:5;url=wherever.php" );` that redirects after sometime, find and remove that.

Comment: @Mubin im not understanding - where can i force it to exit? or die even?

Comment: after displaying the page, I mean where you echo you curl response

Comment: @Mubin That didnt work. Killed the connection still redirects again

Answer (score 0):

use `simple html dom parser` and build dom again, and after that display, hope will not redirect again.

like

```
$page = get_response_from_server();   // your curl function
echo $page = str_get_html($page);    //will stay here(hopefully).
```

I took a closer look over response headers, and I found on header

```
Refresh:8;URL=/some_page.
```

with this header, it'll redirect to `some_page` after `8 seconds`.
So, in my view, changing

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);`

to

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);`

might help.

Answer (score -2):

Change this line from:

```
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
```

to:

```
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

as `0` -> do not set any behaviour.

Remove this line:

```
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```

Comment: I tried this and the $redirect is producing the url but no data is being passed through.